# Azure Container Registry pull request fails with dial tcp lookup no such host

Tags: azure, jenkins, azure-container-registry

Issue : Created a Azure Container Registry .
Using Jenkins to Automate CI/CD .
The image push to the repository is successful. However when we try to pull the image on the same jenkins box it fails with error :

- docker pull simplimedpoc.azurecr.io/bot-demo:latest
  Error response from daemon: Get https://simplimedpoc.azurecr.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup simplimedpoc.azurecr.io on 168.63.129.16:53: no such host

Comment: This runs in a jenkins job :

Comment: stage('ACS Docker Pull and Run') {
           app = docker.image('simplimedpoc.azurecr.io/bot-demo:latest')
           withDockerRegistry([credentialsId: 'acr_credentials', url: 'https://simplimedacr.azurecr.io']) {
           app.pull()

Comment: jenkins@jenkins:~$ az acr login -n simplimedacr -u simplimedacr -p *******
Login Succeeded
jenkins@jenkins:~$ docker pull simplimedpoc.azurecr.io/bot-demo:latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://simplimedpoc.azurecr.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup simplimedpoc.azurecr.io on 168.63.129.16:53: no such host

Comment: edit this into the question and delete comments

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem.  In my case, it was because my registry was in one virtual network and the VM I was using to pull the image was in a different virtual network.  I added "peering" via the portal and was able to pull images after that.